# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/module

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know that this is an error which is often asked about but I did my research and nothing I found seemed to work for me.

So my HTML and Angular Code looks like this:

```js
(function() {
 var app = angular.module('todolist', []);
 
 app.controller('EntryController', function(){
  this.entries = todos;
 });

 var todos = [{
   desc: 'buy eggs for da caek',
   status: 'todo',
  },
  {
   desc: 'do sem poshops',
   status: 'done',
  },
  {
   desc: 'stedy for them exems',
   status: 'todo',
  },
  ];
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todolist">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JS To-Do-List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!--<link data-require="semantic-ui@*" data-semver="0.9.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/0.9.6/build/packaged/css/semantic.min.css" />-->
    <!--<script data-require="semantic-ui@*" data-semver="0.9.6" src="https://raw.github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/0.9.6/build/packaged/javascript/semantic.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>
    
    <!--<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>-->

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="EntryController as entercont">
 <h1 class="center-text">To-Do-List</h1>
    <h4 class="center-text">a JS application straight from hel</h4>
    <hr>

    <div class="addentry">
        <form name="" role="form" >
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <textarea ng-model="" class="form-control" placeholder="Add an entry here..." title="Review"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="submitbtn" value="Submit Entry" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="tododone">
        <div ng-controller="EntryController as entercont">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><h3 class="tablecolumn">To-Do:</h3></th>
                    <th><h3 class="tablecolumn">Change status:</h3></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="todotd" ng-repeat="entry in entercont.entries">
                    <td>
                        {{entry.desc}} <br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.                         
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="">
                            Done: <input ng-show="entry.status === done" type="checkbox" name="status" value="Done" checked="checked">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
           </table>
        </div>
        <br> {{entercont.entries[0].desc}}
    </div>
    <hr>
</body>
<footer>
 
</footer>
</html>
```

And when I try to open the page, all the angular expressions do not get processed by angular as the result will put out {{entry.desc}} or {{entercont.entries[0].desc}}.

When I check the errors via developer tools I get said error message and a lot of errors from that angular.min.js file.

I hope you can help me out here, have been stuck on this for way to long now.

Edit: I'm sorry for being a beginner, feel free to downvote my post.

Comment: Your IIFE is missing one of the I's (the invoked part). It is not being executed, you left off the `()` at the end of it, eg `})()`

Comment: Oh my. Thank you so much. It's the little things in life amirite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit should be given to Patrick Evans too, but this should fix your problem. Moved your 'todos' to inside the controller definition too.

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('todolist', []);

  app.controller('EntryController', function() {
    var todos = [{
      desc: 'buy eggs for da caek',
      status: 'todo',
    },
    {
      desc: 'do sem poshops',
      status: 'done',
    },
    {
      desc: 'stedy for them exems',
      status: 'todo',
    }];
  });

  this.entries = todos;
})();
```

After thinking about it, not sure I have a reason to move the var declaration into the controller, except just for the availability. In practise we do that a lot, in fact it's very rare we would do otherwise, and we have an app of 1.5million lines+...

Comment: I already tried to thank him for his answer but sadly it is not possible to comment on a comment here (I think at least). Could you explain why defining the var inside the controller is better? I learned it differently just wondering.